# Problema com encoding no Git

Tags: git, codificação-de-caracteres

Fiz o clone de um projeto grande mas muitos dos arquivos estavam em unstage e deleted. Percebi que era o encoding do nome do arquivo então configurei em utf-8 assim:

```
git config gui.encoding utf-8
```

Após isso os nomes dos arquivos voltaram ao normal mas alguns não funcionaram, eles foram considerados deletados pelo git:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebi que os mesmo estavam para serem adicionados mas com o nome correto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Diante a isso não consigo corrigir meu branch!

Comment: É apenas a referência do nome no GIT, ele considera que você deletou os arquivos com nome errado e está adicionando os arquivos com o nome correto, não se preocupe você não irá perder seus arquivos.

Comment: Entendo, mas preciso tratar esses arquivos mas como a referencia deles estão quebradas não consigo fazer o controle. Preciso corrigir a referencia dos nomes.

Comment: Acho que quando você comitar as referências ficarão corretas, com os nomes corretos.

Comment: A maioria dos arquivos sim, mas alguns permaneceram deletados. Tentei dar um checkout para ultima versão e renomear mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metade do problema foi resolvido quando o encoding foi definido como utf-8, mas o terminal possivelmente está em iso o que recomendo mudar as configurações do terminal.

Botão direito do mouse > Options > Windows > UI linguagem = utf-8